# Vacation pay owed

Tags: vacation

Early in the month I gave my resignation notice for the end of the month. It was confirmed to me that I had 10 days of paid vacation available.

Shortly after my notice I was informed that I could leave as a replacement was found, however they would pay me through the end of the month.

Do they also owe me for the 10 vacation days?

Comment: Read your employment agreement, and discuss with a lawyer.

Comment: Doesn't this depend on how many days were remaining in the month that you were paid but did not work? Why would they be obligated to add 10 more days?

Comment: This varies a LOT by country and state (if in the US). You need legal advice and unfortunately legal advice isn't what we have here for you.

Comment: Many places in the US do not pay for unused vacation and many do not let you take them once you give notice. Many places do even when it is not legally required.  There are different laws in different places.

Answer (score 3):

After going over the rules;

It depends. Ask them. If they say no, ask why and/or consult an employment lawyer.

Without knowing where you're at it's impossible to give an answer, and even then, you're better off asking an expert (A lawyer)

Comment: This is almost certainly poor advice.

Comment: This is how it works in Canada, I know US employment law can be backwards at times, but is it really that different that "ask them" doesn't even apply?